# C# : How can I encode GUIDs to 11 character ids?

Tags: c#, encode, guid

Like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={id}

{id}:11characters

I try to use Convert.ToBase64String

```
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(guid.ToByteArray())
                .Replace("/", "_")
                .Replace("+", "-").Replace("=", "");
```

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PISrA.png)

The GUIDs is only reduced to 22 characters.

How can I encode GUIDs to 11 character ids?(or less 22 characters)

Comment: Are you actually looking for encryption or just *encoding*?

Comment: sorry, I think it is encoding.

Comment: Do you need to reduce GUID or just shorter unique id ? And does your id must be url friendly ?

Comment: A Guid is 128 bits long. To encode that much data in 11 characters will require each character to contain 11 bits of information. You're not going to achieve this whilst limiting yourself to printable ASCII.

Comment: also note: `Guid.ToByteArray()` uses a *very* atypical byte layout; it *probably* isn't what you want, unless you're only ever going to use it to/from your own code - you certainly don't want it in a public/x-plat API

Comment: Youtube.com does not use a guid, it uses `long`.  Which takes 64 bits, encoded in base64 that takes ceil(64/6) = 11 characters.  A database is a basic way to get a reliable [identity column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_column).

Comment: Thank you everyone, I will try to use other identity columns.

Answer (score 2):

11 characters, even assuming you could use all 8 bits per character in a URL (hint: you can't), would only allow 88 bits.

A UUID/GUID is 128 bits. Therefore, the conversion you propose is not possible without losing data.

Answer (score 1):

This is off topic answer but it might give you an ID with only 11 characters.

In C# a `long` value has 64 bits, which if encoded with Base64, there will be 12 characters, including 1 padding `=`. If we trim the padding `=`, there will be 11 characters.

One crazy idea here is we could use a combination of Unix Epoch and a counter for one epoch value to form a `long` value. The Unix Epoch in C# `DateTimeOffset.ToUnixEpochMilliseconds` is in `long` format, but the first 2 bytes of the 8 bytes are always 0, because otherwise the date time value will be greater than the maximum date time value. So that gives us 2 bytes to place an `ushort` counter in.

So, in total, as long as the number of ID generation does not exceed 65536 per millisecond, we can have an unique ID:

```
// This is the counter for current epoch. Counter should reset in next millisecond
ushort currentCounter = 123;

var epoch = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
// Because epoch is 64bit long, so we should have 8 bytes
var epochBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(epoch);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    // Use big endian
    epochBytes = epochBytes.Reverse().ToArray();
}

// The first two bytes are always 0, because if not, the DateTime.UtcNow is greater 
// than DateTime.Max, which is not possible
var counterBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(currentCounter);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    // Use big endian
    counterBytes = counterBytes.Reverse().ToArray();
}

// Copy counter bytes to the first 2 bytes of the epoch bytes
Array.Copy(counterBytes, 0, epochBytes, 0, 2);

// Encode the byte array and trim padding '='
var shortUid = Convert.ToBase64String(epochBytes).TrimEnd('=');
```

Comment: WoW, It looks so great I will try it later. Thank you.